# using call_user_func_array in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So it is my first time using call_user_func_array, as I recently switched over from mysql, and I am having some difficulties in executing it. I am a little confused about the contents and formatting of the inputs of call_user_func_array are.

This is what I have, starting with an array of message recipients. The purpose of my query is to find the emails and user id's of an unknown number of message recipients

```
$messagerecipients = implode(',', $_POST['messagerecipients']);
$messagerecipients = rtrim($messagerecipients,',');
$messagerecipients = explode(',',$messagerecipients);

$params = array();
 foreach ($messagerecipients as $messagerecipient) {
     $params[$messagerecipient] = $messagerecipient;
 }

var_dump($params);

$getuseridquery = 'SELECT users.username, users.email, users.id FROM users WHERE users.username IN(';
foreach ($params as $id) {
    $getuseridquery .= '?,';
}
```

my $params looks like

```
array(2) { ["joey123"]=> string(6) "joey123" ["micsmith55"]=> string(9) "micsmith55" }
```

this creates:

`SELECT users.username, users.email, users.id FROM users WHERE users.username IN(?,?),`

which looks perfect to me (I am not sure about the $params, but the query looks good)

then I prepare and execute:

```
$getuseridstmt = $mysqli->prepare($getuseridquery);
array_unshift($newParams, str_repeat('s', count($params)));
print count($Params);// this equals '2'
print count($newParams); //this equals '3'
var_dump($newParams);
call_user_func_array(array($getuseridstmt, 'bind_param'), $newParams);
$getuseridstmt->execute();
$getuseridstmt->store_result();
$getuseridstmt->bind_result($username, $useremail, $userid);

$useridarray = array();
$emailaddressarray = array();
while ($getuseridstmt->fetch()) {
    $useridarray[] = $userid;
    $emailaddressarray[] = $useremail;
}
```

but I cannot get anything from those arrays. I barely know how to debug this, which is certainly part of the problem.

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just an observation: Your implode,trim,explode construct can most likely be replaced by `$messagerecipients = array_filter( array_map('trim', $_POST['messagerecipients']), 'strlen');` and then you can build the `IN(?,?,?)` part of the query via `IN(?' .str_repeat(',?', count($messagerecipients)-1) . ')'` (after you have tested that there is at least one parameter(

Comment: Ok I like that. Haven't seen other people use that on the net but that seems like a great idea.